# Javascript - Replace all delimiters apart from the last delimeter

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var txt = 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced'; <-- leave this and not replace the last DELIMETER

txt = txt.replace(/DELIMETER/g, "HI");
```

I understand that all the words that have 'DELIMETER' will be replaced with 'HI', but what i want is just replace the first four occurrences of 'DELIMETER' but leave the last 'DELIMETER' and not replace that word.

How can this be achieved would i have to use regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First break the text into two parts, the part before the last delimiter, and everything after it. Then do the replacement in the first part, and concatenate them together.

```js
var txt = 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';

var match = txt.match(/(.*)(DELIMETER.*)/);
if (match) {
  var [whole, part1, part2] = match;
  part1 = part1.replace(/DELIMETER/g, 'OK');
  txt = part1 + part2;
}
console.log(txt);
```

Comment: I upvoted each answer thx for your suggestions, but this answer was what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mix of regex and javascript. One such way would be to check if it's the last occurrence by using string's `lastIndexOf` and then using a function to iterate through the matches on replace. If the match is at the end, return the matched string (DELIMETER) otherwise, replace with the replacement (HI).

```js
var txt = 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';
txt += 'DELIMETER is replaced';

const target = "DELIMETER";
const replacement = "HI"
const regex = new RegExp(target, 'g');

txt = txt.replace(regex, (match, index) => index === txt.lastIndexOf(target) ? match : replacement);

console.log(txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cut away the last delimiter in advance.

```
var matches = txt.match(/^(.*)(DELIMETER.*)$/)
txt = matches[1].replace(/DELIMETER/g, "HI") + matches[2]
```